# Calling Oracle from C#: Oracle error ORA-12571 encountered

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core

I'm using [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core/2.19.100/) to access Oracle database from C#. The goal is to read pretty big set of data - it contains around 500k records. I'm doing it using data reader:

```
await using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
  // Do Stuff
}
```

With local server it works fine. But when I'm executing it against a remote server, after some time (approx 1 min) I'm getting

> System.Exception: 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
> (0x80004005):  Oracle error ORA-12571 encountered  --->
> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): Oracle error
> ORA-12571 encountered  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
> (10053): An established connection was aborted by the software in your
> host machine.    at
> OracleInternal.Network.TcpTransportAdapter.Send(OraBuf OB)    at
> OracleInternal.Network.TcpTransportAdapter.Send(OraBuf OB)    at
> OracleInternal.Network.WriterStream.Write(OraBuf OB)

Is it some kind of timeout issue? Does anyone know how to solve this? Maybe it's possible to read data not via reader, but the whole?

What I tried:
OracleConnection has parameters KeepAlive, KeepAliveTime - none of them helped.
OracleCommand has parameter CommandTimeout - doesn't help as well.

Comment: what if you execute the SQL outside of C# - such as from sqlplus?